# C# ODBC getSchema("Tables") sends results but getSchema("Columns") returns nothing

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, schema

I have an ODBC connection using a DSN and I am trying to get the tables and columns from it (for manipulation later) but it is failing at an early stage. The database is a FairCom C-tree (v 6.11) if it matters:

```
OdbcConnection odbcConn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Ctree;");
odbcConn.Open();

DataTable tblTables = odbcConn.GetSchema("Tables"); 
foreach (DataRow row in tblTables.Rows) //displays them one at a time (works)
     MessageBox.Show(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());

DataTable tblColumns = odbcConn.GetSchema("Columns"); // (why is this empty?)
foreach (DataRow row in tblColumns.Rows) //lists nothing
     MessageBox.Show(row["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString() + " : " + row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
```

The issue is that getSchema("Tables") works just fine so I know that the connection works, the drivers are in good shape and that data exists. So why is getSchema("Columns") failing? I also know there is data (hundreds of columns and thousands of rows) inside the db. I am at a loss.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Unsure if this works with Faircom C-Tree SQL, but try getting the column schema for a single table.

[`GetSchema()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254934(v=vs.110).aspx) permits the [specification of restrictions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716722(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var restrictions = new string[] { null, null, "TableName" };
odbcConn.GetSchema("Columns", restrictions);
```

You may have to specify the schema name as well (e.g. Sales.SalesPeople)

```
var restrictions = new string[] { null, "Sales", "SalesPeople" };
odbcConn.GetSchema("Columns", restrictions);
```